# Adding file to .apk

Tags: android, resources, apk

My program needs large .txt file to be stored on SD-card (so, I want to redistribute it with .apk, without creation from the program). How I can attach the file (created on PC) to .apk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can save it in `/res/raw` folder
If you save your file as `yourfile.txt`

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.yourfile);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can open a .apk with zip and add files. Where is no magic :)

Comment: I didn't mean this. And anyways, you must sign your .apk before publishing - if you'll modify it, the signatures will not match.

Answer (score 2):

It might be slightly easier to use the AssetManager. Just save your files in the assets/ directory (as opposed to res/raw/). Then you can access them directly using their filename. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html describes how to access the assets.