# Storing static configuration data

Tags: android, configuration, static

I have looked for a solution, but getting solutions for SharedPreferences and SQLite databases. I have to store a single URL that my Android application will access for getting some data. I like to keep that as configurable, as in case I can change the URL and use the app with another set of data.

If I use strings.xml, will I need to repeat the same in case I am adding support for other languages?

For storing in SharedPreferences, I need to store it somewhere till the app is installed to be able to save it there.

Using an SQLite database for this seems too far fetched?

I think the basic thing would be to store it in a Constants class, but I am not sure whether that is the correct approach.

Can someone suggest a better solution?

Comment: use JSON for it's light , fast and complex free

Comment: i would use string.xml .. just not adding the string in other languages's string

Comment: @StinePike, won't it complain that the string resource is missing from other languages, i had say fr_fr/strings.xml as well?

Comment: as far i know .. it does the same like drawable .. that means if something is missing in current configuration .. then it uses from other's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't indicate that the url should remain private.  So, you may be overlooking the obvious.  Why not simply create a "configuration" file that is installed with the application?  This can be achieved by following the methodology [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886521/adding-file-to-apk).  Once it is installed, your application can simple read it and process accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the URL need not be private. All I want is to keep such language independent static configuration data at one place and not inside any Constants class.

Answer (score 1):

In our app we store all static configuration in the AndroidManifest.xml as meta-data properties.

The link to the docs can explain it better than I can:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html

Basically:

```
<meta-data android:name="api.url" android:value="http://api.some-api.com"/>
```

Then assuming the meta-data is at application level, you can get it using:

```
        Bundle data = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
            context.getPackageName(),
            PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).metaData;

        String apiUrl = data.getString("api.url");
```

Comment: If this is something you want to keep private don't follow this method since it's accessible for all the other apps, for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352713

Answer (score 0):

I would store the URL in Constants. unless you need to change it between releases. 
If you want to store it in XML, then put it into `donottranslate.xml`, so that Lint doesn't complain.